# pyparsing infixNotation ParseException

Tags: pyparsing

In python 3.7, i have below logic. Earlier version of pyparsing used operatorPrecedence and the newer version of pyparsing uses infix_notation.

```
    expr << pp.infix_notation(semi_expression, [
           ("not", 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, self.not_operator),
           ("and", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, self.and_operator),
           ("or", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, self.or_operator)
           ])
    result = expr.parseString(filter_str)
    return result
```

However i see traceback

File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/testfilter.py", line 168, in parse_filter_str
result = expr.parseString(filter_str)
pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected 'or' term, found 'serial'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)

Kindly help to solve this ?

Comment: Can you post enough of the code for `semi_expression` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi @PaulMcG, I am the same person who had raised this issue in GitHub. Since we are dealing there, we don't need to handle it here.

Comment: In that case, please close/delete this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of an issue posted to the pyparsing repo.